# Ajax - Django getting pages without refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I'm trying to use ajax in my web app. 
I have a html code like this:

```
<div class="item">
     <div class="menu">

          {% for bas in bslklr %}
            <div class="basliklinki">

              <a class="item" id="baslikl" href="/baslik/{{ bas.title }}">{{ bas }}</a>

            </div>
          {% endfor %}

     </div>       
</div>
<div class="ajaxli-segment">
[code]
</div>
<div class="ajaxli-main">
[code]
</div>
```

and I use this js code:

```
function ajax_get_update()
    {
       $.get(url, function(results){
          var segment = $("div.ajaxli-segment", results);
          var main = $("div.ajaxli-main", results);
          $('.ajaxli-segment').html(segment);
          $('.ajaxli-main').html(main);
        }, "html");
    }

$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( '.basliklinki .item#baslikl' ).click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        url = ($( '.basliklinki .item#baslikl' )[0].href);
        ajax_get_update();
    }); 
});

$( document ).ajaxStop( function() {
    $( '.basliklinki .item#baslikl' ).click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        url = ($( '.basliklinki .item#baslikl' )[0].href);
        ajax_get_update();
    });
});
```

I have all fields for objects in `ajaxli-segment` and `ajaxli-menu` divs in their templates. I want to get them without refreshing the page but my code doesn't work. When I click one of the objects, it empties the `ajaxli-segment` and `ajaxli-main` divs but it doesn't get new content from the page with same divs, that I want to see.
You may see it in action at `munhasir.com`, just open the left sidebar and click one of the lines in there.
How can I make this work? Thanks.

Comment: Is the javascript click function being triggered?

Comment: Yes, it triggered by a tags. It empties the `ajaxli-segment` and `ajaxli-main` divs but it doesn't get new content from the page with same divs, that I want to see.

Comment: You may see it in action at munhasir.com, just open the left sidebar and click one of the lines in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the whole code to this:

```
<div class="item">
     <div class="menu eyceksli" id="ajax_table_result">

          {% for bas in bslklr %}
                <script type="text/javascript">
function ajax_get_update()
    {
       $.get(url, function(results){
          xx =$(results).filter("#mainsegment").html();
          yy =$(results).filter("#mainn").html();

          $('#mainsegment').html(xx);
          $('.ajaxli-main').html(yy);
        }, "html");
    }

$( document ).ready( function() {
    $('.basliklinki #baslikl{{ bas.id }}').click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        url = ($('.basliklinki #baslikl{{ bas.id }}')[0].href);
        ajax_get_update();
    }); 
});

$( document ).ajaxStop( function() {
    $('.basliklinki #baslikl{{ bas.id }}').click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        url = ($('.basliklinki #baslikl{{ bas.id }}')[0].href);
        ajax_get_update();
    });
});
</script>
            <div class="basliklinki">

              <a class="item" id="baslikl{{ bas.id }}" href="{% url 'tek_baslik' bas.title %}" style="color:#05377E;">{{ bas }} {% if bas.gunentry > 0 %} ({{ bas.gunentry }}) {% endif %}</a>


            </div>
          {% endfor %}

          <br>
     </div>      
</div>
```